# Capture when a user changes the NativeTimeline slicer view state (i.e. months to qrts)

Tags: excel, pivot-table, vba

I've been racking my brain on this and am stuck.  In the Excel NativeTimeline slicer I want to capture when a user switches from Months to Quarters so I can then update the time series chart on the dashboard.  I can't seem to find a way to hook into this though as the change is only effecting what is displayed, nothing in the pivot table (otherwise I could use an event trigger there).

I've tried adding it to a custom class and setting it to a public withevents object, but that didn't work. Any other ideas on how I can capture this?

Here's the the code to switch to Quarters and then Months.

```
ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("NativeTimeline_WeekBeginDate").Slicers("WeekBeginDate").TimelineViewState.Level = xlTimelineLevelQuarter
ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("NativeTimeline_WeekBeginDate").Slicers("WeekBeginDate").TimelineViewState.Level = xlTimelineLevelMonths
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your only hope is to deselect the "Time Level" option so users can't change it on the TimeLine, and instead add a toggle button that lets the user select the time level there, then use their selection to not only change the time level on the TimeLine but also change your time series chart.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but I decided to keep the native feature and just update on slicer value change

Answer (score 0):

In case others come across this, there currently is no way to capture this event so this is the best work around I could come up with. I capture the pivot table change event, check the Level for the Timeline slicer, and then update the pivot table as needed.  The only problem with this is that it is not triggered when the user changes the time level, only after the change the time filter.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_PivotTableChangeSync(ByVal Target As PivotTable)
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    If Target = "PivotTable4" Then
        On Error Resume Next    'this will throw an error if a month/quarter is selected with no data
        If ThisWorkbook.SlicerCaches("NativeTimeline_WeekDate").Slicers("WeekDate").TimelineViewState.Level = xlTimelineLevelQuarters Then
            'change times series chart to quarters
            ptDashboard.PivotTables("PivotTable4").PivotFields("WeekDate").LabelRange.Group _
                Start:=True, End:=True, Periods:=Array(False, False, False, False, False, True, True)   'group by quarter & year

        ElseIf ThisWorkbook.SlicerCaches("NativeTimeline_WeekDate").Slicers("WeekDate").TimelineViewState.Level = xlTimelineLevelMonths Then
            'change times series chart to months
            ptDashboard.PivotTables("PivotTable4").PivotFields("WeekDate").LabelRange.Group _
                Start:=True, End:=True, Periods:=Array(False, False, False, False, True, False, True)   'group by months & year
        End If
        On Error GoTo 0
    End If
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```